# How can you read in a file in R when there is a second header in the middle of the data?

Tags: r

I can only seem to find a python solution that I can't adapt to R...
I am trying to read in a batch of .txt files, and two of them threw errors. After investigation, I realized there is a second header in the middle of the file (around line 40,000/100,000).

This is what the error files look like (assuming like 30000 additional lines above and below):

2017/6/22,11:27:46,9.79e3,20740,0.976,1008
2017/6/22,11:27:47,9.63e3,20412,0.976,1008
2017/6/22,11:27:48,9.76e3,20691,0.976,1008
DATA INSTRUMENT NAME
112346789,2017/6/22,12:30:50
1
1.04,130
Model 1000 Ver 1.27 S/N 987654321
"Date","Time","Concentration","header","header","header"
2017/6/22,12:30:50,1.50e4,31470,0.962,1010
2017/6/22,12:30:52,1.44e4,30110,0.964,1009
2017/6/22,12:30:53,1.20e4,25275,0.969,1010

Anyone know how to just read in the file without these 6 lines? I've been using fread but I don't see how I can add a line of code to recognize strings that don't all start with the same character..

Thanks!

Comment: Here are two options: (1) `read.csv` supports both `skip=` and `nrows=`, which lets you choose exactly which lines of the file to read in, rather literal. (2) `txt <- readLines("file.csv")` the whole file in, then split up into blocks of text with something like `multidats <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl('"Date"', txt))) |> lapply(read.csv)`. This likely needs to be tempered since you appear to have _three_ chunks of data, the first few without a header. You can probably reuse one of the other headers for the first if needed.

Comment: To add to r2evans' suggestion:   write a little loop involving `grep` to identify the row index of every line that starts with "DATA INSTRUMENT" . Then  remove rows `j` thru `j+6`